# How to a List<string> in razor from a value from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Skills save in database under column `Skills` the save data in backhand is like this `Android App, Android, Android App Development, Android SDK` here is a snapshot of column.
[image]

i want to display this in user side like this

[image]

here is a .cshtml code:

```
<div class="job-detail-content mt-30 clearfix">
                <div class="post-tags clr">
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">CSS3</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">Directory</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">Freelancer</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">HTML</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">HTML5</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">Job Board</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">CSS3</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">Directory</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">Freelancer</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">HTML</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">HTML5</a>
                    <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">Job Board</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have bind skill data in

```
public string Skills { get; set; }
```

i want to show this `Skills` data as per 2nd snapshot. and want to wright some code in .cshtml for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is create a `ViewModel` for this view,
inside that `ViewModel` it will contain a property that is a `List<string>`

e.g.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<string> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public Action GetSkills()
{
    var skills = "Android App, Android"; // Data from DB
    var model = new ViewModel
    {
        Skills = skills.Split(',').ToList(),
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Now when you return that new ViewModel to the view you can do something like the following:

```
<div class="job-detail-content mt-30 clearfix">
    <div class="post-tags clr">
        @foreach(var skill in Model.Skills)
        {
            <a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">@skill</a>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dose i split it under detail.cs during binding job detail
`public string Skills { get; set; }
        public List<string> SkillSplit { get; set; }`
`public void BindJob()
        {
            App_Data.Job Job = null;
            string message = String.Empty;
            if (!JobExists(JOBID, out Job, ref message))
                throw new ArgumentException(message, "JOBID");
            Skills = Job.Skills;         
        }`

Answer (score 0):

assume we have a list of passengers called *Passengers* and we want to show all the passengers.

```
public Class Passenger {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

List<Passenger> Passengers = new List<Passenger>();


string passengers = @String.Join(", ", Passengers.Select(x => x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName).ToList());
```

just use *passengers* wherever you want!

Answer (score -1):

u need to get reords from db and loop over to create each element lyk-
in controllor ;assuming skill is string,

```
ViewBag.Skills=objectcontext.<Skills>().Select(p=>p.Skill).ToList();
```

in view

```
<div class="job-detail-content mt-30 clearfix">
            <div class="post-tags clr">
@foreach(skill k in ViewBag.Skills){
<a href="#" rel="tag" data-wpel-link="internal">@skill</a>

  @}
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Skills` is column in job table